# derivative with power and chain rule

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

How would I take the derivative of this with respect to $\eta$?

$$
f = \frac{1}{2}\left[ -3 + \frac{27}{(2+x)^2} + \frac{1-\frac{1}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2}}{C(\eta)} + 2log(x)   \right]
$$

Since $x$ is not dependent on $\eta$, then 3 of the terms go away. So I would have:

$$
\frac{df}{d\eta} = \frac{d}{d\eta}\left[ \frac{1-\frac{1}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2}}{2C(\eta)}    \right]
$$

Now clearly the chain rule and power rule will be needed. I am getting somewhat confused however. Here is an attempt at the quotient rule:

$$
\frac{2C(\eta)\frac{d}{d\eta} \left( 1-\frac{1}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2} \right)   - \left( 1-\frac{1}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2} \right)2C'(\eta) }{\left[ 2C(\eta) \right]^2}
$$

Obviously, the $2's$ cancel:

$$
\frac{C(\eta)\frac{d}{d\eta} \left( 1-\frac{1}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2} \right)   - \left( 1-\frac{1}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2} \right)C'(\eta) }{2\left[ C(\eta) \right]^2}
$$

Now I am still left with the derivative you can see in the numerator. Isolating that, I have:

$$
\frac{d}{d\eta} \left( 1-\frac{1}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2} \right) 
$$

And the first term is 0, so we have:

$$
\frac{d}{d\eta} \left( \frac{-1}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2} \right) 
$$

Now

$$
\frac{\left([1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2\right)(0) + \frac{d}{d\eta}[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^4}
$$

Reducing:

$$
\frac{ \frac{d}{d\eta}[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^4}
$$

So I have:

$$
\frac{2[1+(x-1)C(\eta)](x-1)C'(\eta)}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^4}
$$

Putting it back into the equation above:

$$
\frac{C(\eta)\frac{2[1+(x-1)C(\eta)](x-1)C'(\eta)}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^4}   - \left( 1-\frac{1}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2} \right)C'(\eta) }{2\left[ C(\eta) \right]^2}
$$

does this look correct?

Comment: "Since x is not dependent on η".  But is $\eta$ dependent upon $x$.  In theory, you are correct-- $x$ is treated as a constant, but I am *highly* dubious that this was the text's intent.  If not you must either somehow replace $x$ with a functional invers of $eta$ or do a substitution with $\frac f{dx} =\frac f{d\eta}\frac {d\eta}{dx}$ and do some manipulation to figure $\frac {f}{d\eta}$.

Comment: This is not a homework problem. $x$ is not dependent on $\eta$

Comment: "This is not a homework problem. x is not dependent on η " in that case, treat $x$ as a constant.

Comment: yes, I did this. Does the rest of my solution look ok?

Comment: Oops,,,,, never mind.

Comment: I didn't go over it with a fine tooth comb but it looks like you know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify
$$
 \frac{1-\frac{1}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2}}{C(\eta)} 
$$
to
$$\frac{1}{C(\eta)}-\frac{1}{[1+(x-1)C(\eta)]^2C(\eta)}$$
before taking the derivative.